# Mantle parsing array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, github-mantle

I am using mantle `framework` to parse `JSON` file.
My `JSON` object Looks like this

```
[{
   key:value
   key:value
 },
 {
   key:value
   key:value
 } ]
```

My object is `array` that doesn't have key. 
How could we parse this `array`? How should the `JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey` method be implemented?

As mentiond on the Library description

> This method Specifies how to map property keys to different key paths
>   in `JSON`

```
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {

      return @{
        @"items" : @"",
      };
```

So how could we map `array` property to `JSON` object that doesn't have a key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, You are getting an array in response of an API call and you want to parse it.

So as per your JSON. You need to create a MTLModel subclass for the type of objects in the array.

Then you can parse the array and create the models of the object types in array. Like this:

```
NSArray *objects = [MTLJSONAdapter modelsOfClass:[model class] fromJSONArray:[PASS THE ARRAY] error:nil];
```

Hope that helps.